# Is it possible to make a button that prints many pages of a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, printing

I have to create a button that can prints many pages of the website I am working on.

I tried to add all the html of the pages I need to print to document.
My idea is to print thanks to `window.print()`, but I have many bugs due to the javascript content (which uses dom) of each pages.

This is my current code :

```
  var homeInnerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
  var htmlToPrint = "";
  <% User.all.order(:name).each do |user| %>
  <% Project.where(chief: user.id).order(:title).each do |project| %>
  $.get("/sheet?id=<%= project.id %>", function(data) {
    htmlToPrint += data;
  });
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
  function printAll() {
    document.open();
    document.write(htmlToPrint);
    document.close();
    window.print();

    document.open();
    document.write(homeInnerHTML);
    document.close();
  }
```

I don't have any other ideas of what can I do, and if it exists a neat way with a good user experience to do it.

Comment: It may be possible but it is far easier/better to just create a route, action and view that displays the resources. Such as `/projects/:project_id/sheets` or `/users/:user_id/projects`.

Comment: Yes it is, I will do that, thank you.